# Pythonのruntime errorについて

Tags: python

現在、友人3人であつまってPythonの独習を始めました。
昨日夜も皆で同じコードを書いていたのですが一人だけ
「type error 'int'objyect is not callble」
と出てしまい止まってしまいました。
友人は「runtime errorではないか」と言っていましたがその場合は表示がruntimeと出るように思います。

私のPCでは再現できなくて原因を突き止めにくいのですが、仮説として「runtime error」はあるのでしょうか。（検索した所、Runtime error は同時に複数のアクセスが発生すると起きると書いてありました）
もし、何かご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただければ幸いです。
（次回の勉強会で検証してみたいので・・）

使用したコード

```
data = [56, 45, 83, 67, 59, 41, 77]
print(sum(data))
print(max(data))
print(min(data))
```

Comment: 何を質問してるのかよく伝わらないけど,
Run-timeエラーは (エラーが)コンパイル時と実行時に分かれてる場合はともかく, 基本的に Pythonはインタープリターなので Run-timeにしか問題出ないはず (別の意味の質問であればすみません)。
エラーの原因の方は例えば `sum = 123; sum([10,20])` など実行すれば int型は callableでない(int型を関数みたいに呼び出そうとした) 的なメッセージ出るはずです

Comment: そのとき参考にしていた記事や書籍とか、それのどの辺をやろうとしていたか、といった情報を追記すると現象の特定に結びつくかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

たとえば `sum` という変数を新しく宣言してしまうと、組み込み関数の `sum` が使えなくなり、質問文にあるようなエラーが出ます。組み込み関数の `sum` ではなくて新しく定義した変数に対して関数呼び出しが行われるからです。

```
>>> data = [56, 45, 83, 67, 59, 41, 77]
>>> sum = sum(data)
>>> print(sum)
428
>>> print(sum(data))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

インタプリター上で色々と試している内に上記のような感じで組み込み関数の上書きが起こったのかもしれません。

---

なお補足として、Python の組み込み例外である [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) と、いわゆる「実行時例外」は区別して覚えておくようにしてください。エラーメッセージに書いてあるようにこれは [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) であり `RuntimeError` ではありません。一方で今回のエラーは構文エラーや静的な型検査エラーではなく、実行時エラーです。